# Automapper with mutator

Tags: c#, properties, set, automapper

Seems simple to me but not working as expected. Source class:

```
public class SourceTest
{
  private string _field1;
  public string Field1
  {
    get
    {
      return _field1;
    }
    set
    {
      _field1 = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Destination class:

```
public class DestTest
{
  private string _field1;
  public string Field1
  {
    get
    {
      return _field1;
    }
    set
    {
      _field1 = value.ToUpper();
    }
  }
}
```

The point is the destination class is formatting the input value.

Test code:

```
  Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
  {
    cfg.BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance  BindingFlags.NonPublic; 
  });

  SourceTest st = new SourceTest();
  st.Field1 = "John";

  DestTest dt = new DestTest();

  AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceTest, DestTest>();
  AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SourceTest, DestTest>(st, dt);
  MessageBox.Show(dt.Field1);
```

the destination object's Field1 is not in uppercase. The set code is called as I can put a breakpoint in it.

Is this just it supported? I thought it would be a common requirement - the user enters data in one object but we want to process it in a destination object. It's the mapper.initialize including non public fields which is the issue.

Thanks in advance,

Ray

Comment: Are you saying it's *not* capitalising the value even though the code is called?  If so, this isn't possible. I've just run a test, and `dt.Field1` is `JOHN`.  As an aside, a setter that does this is rather surprising - an end user of an APi wouldn't expect a property to return a different value to the one set.

Comment: Hi Charles.Thanks for taking the time and testing - it's definitely not capitalizing the value in my test. Seeing as it worked for you I placed in in a stand alone application and it does work as expected, and as it worked for you. My issue is that in the real app. this is stopping itg from working the way I want: 
      Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
      {
        cfg.BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
      });

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'd definitely add that into the question.  My guess is that as you've allowed it to bind private fields, it's writing to both but not in the order you'd like.  I don't know enough about AutoMapper, though.